# Unhandled Runtime Error - SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

This error is occurring when running npm run dev, can anyone help me solve it?

```
import {useState} from "react";

export function useLocalStorage<T>(item: string) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(item) ?? ''))
    const updateLocalStorage = (newValue: T) => {
        setValue(newValue);
        localStorage.setItem(item, JSON.stringify (newValue));
    }
    return {
        value,
        updateLocalStorage
    }
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htgY3.png)

Comment: An empty string is not valid json ...